# Create enough headers to accommodate all results

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, office365, export-to-csv

My script is here:

```psh
$Results = @()
Get-Mailbox | % {
  $o = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
         'DisplayName'         = $_.DisplayName
         'alias'               = $_.alias
         'UserPrincipalName'   = $_.UserPrincipalName
         'PrimarySmtpAddress'  = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
         'PrimaryProxyAddress' = ($_.EmailAddresses) -cmatch "SMTP:" -replace '^smtp:' -join ' ' 
       }

  $i = 1
  $_.EmailAddresses -cmatch "smtp:" | % {
    $o | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "OtherProxyAddress$i" `
      -Value ($_ -replace '^smtp:')
    $i++
  }

  $Results += $o
}

$results| ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | clip
```

The problem is when I convert to CSV. When converting to CSV, it takes the first mailbox how many `OtherProxyAddress` are in there. If there's two `OtherProxyAddress` in the first mailbox, it will use this and go and create the headings for the CSV file. However, some mailboxes might have more than 2 `OtherProxyAddress` fields. In this instance, when I open the CSV in Excel, I miss other entries for the mailboxes that have more than two `OtherProxyAddress` fields.

I want to be able to capture in CSV format, so I can paste into Excel which enough headers at the top to match the mailbox with the most `OtherProxyAddress` fields.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the exported data? Usually it's not a good idea to create objects with a variable number of properties if you want to export as CSV. You could create a "multi-valued" field by joining the elements with a (different) delimiter character, so you can easily split the elements when re-importing the data.

Comment: Addendum: when pasting the data into Excel, you could use `Text to Columns` for splitting a column with delimited values. You just need to make sure to have enough blank columns right of the column with your data (so you don't overwrite other values).

Comment: I feel like something is wrong at the beginning as well. You have variable called `$UserPrincipalName` but I don't see where you populate it.

Comment: @Matt That's a copy/paste error in my previous answer. Fixed here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not my best work but it seems to get the job done. I think I might have changed the properties you wanted but I needed to rearrange things to get the dynamic portion of how the works.

```psh
$all = Get-Mailbox
$maxProxyIndex = $all | Select EmailAddresses | Where-Object{$_.EmailAddresses -cmatch "smtp"} | ForEach-Object{
    ($_.EmailAddresses -split "," | Where-Object{$_  -cmatch "smtp"} | Measure-Object).Count
} | Measure-Object -Maximum | Select -ExpandProperty Maximum

$propertyOrder = "DisplayName","Alias","UserPrincipalName","PrimarySmtpAddress" + (1..$maxProxyIndex | ForEach-Object{"ProxyAddress$_"})

$all | ForEach-Object{
    $props = @{
         'DisplayName'         = $_.DisplayName
         'alias'               = $_.alias
         'UserPrincipalName'   = $_.UserPrincipalName
         'PrimarySmtpAddress'  = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
       }
    $proxyAddresses = @(($_.EmailAddresses -split ","| Where-Object{$_  -cmatch "smtp"})) -replace "^smtp:"
    For($proxyIndex = 1; $proxyIndex -le $maxProxyIndex;$proxyIndex++){
        $props."ProxyAddress$proxyIndex" = If($proxyAddresses){$proxyAddresses[$proxyIndex - 1]}
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props
} | Select-Object $propertyOrder | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Clip
```

First, just like you said, we need to figure out a mailbox with the largest number of proxy addresses which is what `$maxProxyIndex` is. We collect all mailboxes data as we need to parse it twice. Once for the max index and second for the overall output.

For `$maxProxyIndex` we take the `emailaddresses` of each mailbox and filter the secondary smtp emails. We then use `Measure-Object -Maximum` to get us that magic number.

When we create our object output in the main loop we need to always create the other proxy properties even if they don't exist.

You will see that we are using `$propertyOrder` which is important since the dynamic creation of properties does not give a proper order in output.

**[Ansgar Wiechers' Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers)**

None of this is required as you could just leverage an Excel feature to accomplish a similar goal. Per his comment:

> Addendum: when pasting the data into Excel, you could use `Text to Columns` for splitting a column with delimited values. You just need to make sure to have enough blank columns right of the column with your data (so you don't overwrite other values)